# Artifact for contract "UniswapV3Factory" not found using Hardhat

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, uniswapv3

I'm trying to deploy Uniswap v3 locally. I launched a local node with a main net fork using Alchemy like this:

`npx hardhat node --fork https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/{API KEY}`

My code is as simple as that:

```
const mainnetFactoryAddress = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984"
const FactoryDeployedContract = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("UniswapV3Factory", mainnetFactoryAddress);
```

And this is the error output I'm getting:

```
HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "UniswapV3Factory" not found. 
    at Artifacts._handleWrongArtifactForContractName (UniV3-test-hardhat/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:678:11)
    at Artifacts._getArtifactPathFromFiles (UniV3-test-hardhat/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:803:19)
    at Artifacts._getArtifactPath (UniV3-test-hardhat/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:483:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Artifacts.readArtifact (UniV3-test-hardhat/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:71:26)
    at getContractAt (UniV3-test-hardhat/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:314:22)
    at main (UniV3-test-hardhat/scripts/deploy.js:57:35)
```

I'm having trouble figuring out why it can't seem to find the artificat for the factory contract. Anyone would have an hint or a solution for this problem please?

Edit: I also installed the npm `@uniswap/v3-core` package and also have this line at the top: `const UniswapV3Factory = require('@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol/UniswapV3Factory.json');`

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this using any one of the following ways:

1. Install the npm package `@uniswap/v3-core` and import the factory bytecode located at `@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol/UniswapV3Factory.json`

*For example:*

```
import {
  abi as FACTORY_ABI,
  bytecode as FACTORY_BYTECODE,
} from '@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol/UniswapV3Factory.json'

// deploy the bytecode
```

2. Import `UniswapV3Factory` interface from the npm package to any of your smart contracts and compile using hardhat

*For example:*

```
import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol";

contract MyContract {
    // Your contract code 
}
```

3. Copy the contract source code manually to your hardhat project and compile. Hardhat will generate contract Artifacts for you in the same project repo

For more details, check [Uniswap V3 Github repo](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have this packaged installed already, and used it to import the necessary `json`. Btw how would I be able to deploy the contract just with the bytecode please?

Comment: You can deploy a contract just with the bytecode using `eth_sendTransaction` call. The data field would be your contract bytecode(appended by constructor arguments if any). For more details, check here: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sendtransaction